# How to autofill cells for only the visible ones?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I filtered some data and now this I am trying to autofill the visible cells with a vlookup formula (filtered ones). Afterwards, I copy and paste as values. I am not sure how to do so as this is not working:

```
    MasterList.Columns(3).ClearContents
    MasterList.Range("C1").Value = "Client Name"
    MasterList.Range("C2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'Reporting Here'!A:F,5,FALSE)"
    MasterList.Activate
    MasterList.Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & RowCountTotal)
    'copy and paste as values
    MasterList.Range("C2:C" & RowCountTotal).Copy
    MasterList.Range("C2:C" & RowCountTotal).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I don't think that this row is working:

```
MasterList.Range("C2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'Reporting Here'!A:F,5,FALSE)"
```

How do I copy paste the vlookup formulas into only the visible cells after filtering?

Comment: I might not understand what you're trying to do or what part isn't working, but: would it work if you do something like 'MasterList.Range("C2").Copy' and then 'MasterList.Range("C2:C" & RowCountTotal).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas' ?

Comment: I am trying to autofill the vlookup for only the visible cells after I filtered. When I run what you said I get 1004 : "Autofill method of range class failed".

Comment: Aha, oops! Thanks @orange123.

Answer (score 0):

### Visible Cells

```vb
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = MasterList.Range("C2:C" & RowCountTotal) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rg.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,'Reporting Here'!A:F,5,FALSE),"""")"
Dim arg As Range
For Each arg In rg.Areas
    arg.Value = arg.Value
Next arg
```